# Condicionar limite de Archivos con OpenFileDialog en ciclo ForEach

Tags: c#, eventos, foreach, diálogo

En el siguiente ejemplo de mi Evento, Condición de Busco, el ciclo Para cada uno, son solo 3 elementos, el acuerdo, la lista, y la información adicional.

```
private void AtenderBusqueda(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        OpenFileDialog BuscarReportes = new OpenFileDialog();
        BuscarReportes.Multiselect = true;
        BuscarReportes.Filter = "Archivos|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
        BuscarReportes.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        if (BuscarReportes.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (string Archivo in BuscarReportes.FileNames)
            Vista.lista.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Archivo));
            ControlNotificacion.MostrarNotificacion("Carga Correcta", TipoNotificacion.Default, Posicion.InferiorDerecha);


        }
        else
        {
            ControlNotificacion.MostrarNotificacion("No se realizo carga", TipoNotificacion.Advertencia, Posicion.InferiorDerecha);


        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ControlNotificacion.MostrarNotificacion("Se ha Producido un Error: " + ex, TipoNotificacion.Alerta, Posicion.InferiorDerecha);
    }
}
```

Comment: pero quieres hacer esto como validacion, digo informando que seseleciono mas de uno he informarlo pero no continuar o quieres de la seleccion solo tomar los primeros 3 ?

Comment: En efecto @LeandroTuttini deseo Condicionar el evento de Carga a 3 Elementos informar y no continuar la carga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes limitar el número de archivos seleccionados capturando el evento FileOk del OpenFileDialog y condicionándolo a lo que necesitas, en este caso un límite de tres ficheros, que si no cumple cancela el evento:

```
void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = (OpenFileDialog)sender;
    if (dlg.FileNames.Length > 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Límite de tres ficheros...");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Añade esta línea al código para capturar el evento de FileOk:

```
BuscarReportes.FileOk +=openFileDialog1_FileOk;
```

Comment: Probaré en un momento y comento al respecto.

Comment: Estoy verificando, pero para ello debería cambiar el RoutedEventArgs a CancelEventArgs lo cual Afecta la funcion del boton de Carga, alguna idea de complementar.?

Comment: No entiendo a lo que te refieres, tu método "AtenderBusqueda" no se modifica. Lo que tienes que hacer es controlar el evento FileOk, que se lanza cuando el usuario le de a Aceptar despues de mostrar la ventana. Edito para que veas como asignar el evento por código.

Comment: Agradezco, ya he solucionado basado en tu respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando dices límite de archivos, si te refieres al tamaño lo puedes controlar de la siguiente manera.
Con FileInfo puedes obtener el tamaño del archivo, y con el éste puedes controlar el límite

```
var size = new FileInfo(BuscarReportes.FileName).Length;
if(size <= tamaño_que_quieras)...
```

Si te refieres a que el foreach realice 3 loops solamente, contrólalo con un cont y cuando llegue a 3, dejas de cargar.

```
    var cont = 1;
    foreach (string Archivo in BuscarReportes.FileNames){
       if(cont <= 3){
          Vista.lista.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Archivo));
          ControlNotificacion.MostrarNotificacion("Carga Correcta", TipoNotificacion.Default, Posicion.InferiorDerecha);
          cont++;
       }       
    }
```

Comment: En este caso, por alguna razón me deja de respetar los filtros para el tipo de Archivo, poquee consideras que pase?